# Failed to launch chrome!, failed to launch chrome puppeteer in bamboo for jest image snapshot test

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, bamboo, jest-image-snapshot

I am trying to run puppeteer in bamboo build run. But seems there is problem to execute it properly. The detail error below

[image]

I wonder if there is stuff I have to install to get it able to run in bamboo? or I have to do other alternative. There is no articles available online regarding this issue.

And a bit more background, I am trying to implement jest-image-snapshot into my test process. and making a call to generate snapshot like this

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let browser;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  });

  it('show correct page: variant', async () => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(
      'http://localhost:8080/app/register?experimentName=2018_12_STREAMLINED_ACCOUNT&experimentVariation=STREAMLINED#/'
    );
    const image = await page.screenshot();

    expect(image).toMatchImageSnapshot();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await browser.close();
  });
```

the reason log of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'newPage' of undefined` is because `const page = await browser.newPage();`

Answer (score 0):

The important part is in your screenshot:

> Failed to launch chrome! ... No usable sandbox!

Try to launch puppeteer without a sandbox like this:

```js
await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
});
```

Depending on the platform, you might also want to try the following arguments (also in addition):

- `--disable-setuid-sandbox`
- `--disable-dev-shm-usage`

If all three do not work, the [Troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting) might have additional information.